# Emberjs - how to remove pluralization of URLs?

Tags: ember.js

I am building an emberjs app and I want to call my REST API for results. I have this code:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend();
App.PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({   
    namespace: 'api/v1',
    host: 'http://myapp.com'
});
```

And in the controller I have this

```
post: this.store.find('post')
```

The problem is that it always calls with "s" added in the end, for example - `http://myapp.com/api/v1/posts`

How do I remove the plural form from these calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override the `pathForType` method in your adapter.

```
   App.PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({   
     pathForType: function(type) {
       var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
       return Ember.String.singularize(camelized);
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var inflector = new Ember.Inflector();
inflector.singularize('posts');
```

Ember put 's' automatically. You need to force it to use singular. Above code tells Ember to request to `myapp.com/post` when you call `this.store.find('post');` otherwise default behaviour will try to send request to `myapp.com/posts`

I had same issue once upon a time. I could not even found a way to set this behaviour globally. I have repeated this code ( `inflector.singularize('posts');` ) for every store.

Comment: Can you explain your answer?